# parseFloat() usage with numbers started with 0

Tags: jquery, replace, parsefloat

Im interested in why does parseFloat() return 0 in this case:

```
var priceFromJson = '0,33';
console.log(priceFromJson);
            var tmpPrice = parseFloat(priceFromJson);
            console.log('tmpPrice'+tmpPrice);
            var price = parseFloat( ( tmpPrice ) * 1.2 ).toFixed(2);
            console.log('price'+price);
```

result is:

```
0,33 
tmpPrice0 
price0.00
```

But if I do this:

```
var priceFromJson = '0,33';
console.log(priceFromJson);
            var tmpPrice = parseFloat( priceFromJson.replace(',','.') );
            console.log('tmpPrice'+tmpPrice);
            var price = parseFloat( ( tmpPrice ) * 1.2 ).toFixed(2);
            console.log('price'+price);
```

The result is:

```
0,33 
tmpPrice0.33 
price0.40
```

By http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp , but in my case the first char is zero.

Any idea?

EDITED (after comment):

So other decimals, for ex. "5,36" , "10,44" are works fine without the replace(). Any other idea, what should I do in these situations? What is the best method to eliminate this problem then practice it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because of localisation.

The expected decimal separator is `.`, not `,`.

Because `.` is working in all cases, I'd recommend to convert the numbers always (use your replace code). It does not hurt if you canonize the data representation.

Comment: But other option when the input string is for.ex. "5,36" it works.. ?

Comment: Your example shows that `0,33` is not working and `0.33` is working. So should `5.36`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this example 0,33, I try to edit the example.